# When I try to access visual svn server from svn tortoise,it gives me an error 502 proxy error

Tags: proxy, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Please tell me a way to access VisualSVN Server from another machine using a TortoiseSVN client. Every time I try it gives me a `502 proxy error`.

Answer (score 1):

A 502 error is a "bad gateway". Check what layers you have between client and server (i.e. firewall) and make sure you're blocking not blocking the port or IP at that level. Also not sure if you're doing this over HTTPS or HTTP; I've had problems with the SSL route before and setting the server back to HTTP resolved it (assuming this is acceptable to you).